# Is there any to use spinner in synchronous ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

Is there any to use spinner in synchronous ajax call?
Actually browser freeze during call till the response comes.

Comment: A synchronous XHR call in the JavaScript on a web page will freeze the entire browser UI/interaction - including any DOM manipulations or animations. This is a good reason why asynchronous calls should be prefered.

Comment: more like a xy problem then a spinner problem